# Como converter hora em string para time de Ionic para PHP com MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic, localstorage

Bom dia pessoal, estou passando para o servidor uma string que seria para time: 23:45 é um exemplo.

Em meu $_GET estou tentando converter desta forma:

```
$prazo_entrega_min = time("hh:mm", strtotime($_GET['prazo_entrega_min']));
```

Mas sem sucesso. O que posso fazer?

Estou utilizando em meu controller para pegar esta data o plugin ionicTimePicker (https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker):

```
// TEMPO ENTREGA MINIMO
        var ipObj1 = {
            callback: function (val) { //Mandatory
                if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('Time not selected');
                } else {
                    var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
                    console.log(selectedTime.getUTCHours(), 'H :', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'M');

                    $scope.entrega_min = selectedTime.getUTCHours() + ':' + selectedTime.getUTCMinutes();

                    window.localStorage.setItem("prazo_min_entrega", $scope.entrega_min)

                    console.log($scope.entrega_min);
                }
            },
            inputTime: 50400, //Optional
            format: 24, //Optional
            step: 15, //Optional
            setLabel: 'OK' //Optional
        };

        $scope.openTimePicker = function () {
            ionicTimePicker.openTimePicker(ipObj1);
        };
```

Estou armazenando em meu localstorage os valores apenas para conferir, estão todos em string:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que faço de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando a função errada:

```
$prazo_entrega_min = time("hh:mm", strtotime($_GET['prazo_entrega_min']));
```

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php) não aceita argumentos, sempre traz a hora local UTC. A sintaxe que você usou se parece mais com a de [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) (que na verdade seria `H:i` para hora:minutos), mas retornaria uma data formatada.

Se o valor do seu $_GET é a `string` ***23:45*** e você precisa transformar em uma timestamp, use

```
$prazo_entrega_min = strtotime( $_GET['prazo_entrega_min'] );
```

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) sozinha já faz o que você precisa.

Comment: Com o strtotime() apenas, 14:00 ele armazena como 838:59:59

Comment: @ramos seu código deve estar modificando a variável `prazo_entrega_min` depois disso então. Veja aqui os valores originais das funções: https://eval.in/746598